# How to Restore the Mail Symlinks to External Drive on 10.11?

Tags: mail.app, external-disk, macos, symlink

My Mac Mail has been working using an external drive for the library and all messages since 2013.  However I upgraded to 10.11 today and need to find a way to reference everything on the external drive again.  Any thoughts on how to update the Symlinks for 10.11?

I don't have enough drive space on the HD to move or import the folders back plus it would be extremely time consuming...